# Timestamp vs Replay attack

Tags: attack-prevention, timestamp

1) A → B : username, timestamp, h(password)

2) A → B : username, h(password), h(timestamp)

Can above two formula prevent from suffering replay attack?

I think 1 is immune from replay attack but i am not sure about second one.

Can any one help me?

Comment: The best replay attack prevention for most systems is to use SSL. Then you can just send username and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None will protect against a replay attact.

In the first case, all the attacker has to do is adjust the timestamp.

In the second case, since H() is not supposed to be secret and since the timestamp is known, and attacker can also adjust the request by creating a valid H(timestamp). There is also the problem that you need to synchronize the client and server so that they both have the same timestamp value.

The best way to prevent replay attack is to use [challenge-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) (there are other ways to do that, depending on your needs).

Comment: great help, thank you so much!                                                                       i understand first case now.                                                                              For second case, i am not completely understand. Ins't the H() supposed to be irreversible? Can you elaborate more?like if an attacker knows the H(), how can the attacker change the request?@Stephane

Comment: I've added some details to my answer